# Dynamic sections and rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have Task and List, those are 2 entities in database.

```
Task-->one to one-->List
List-->one to many-->Task.
```

I have UITableView where I want to show list like sections and tasks like rows in those sections, but only if thery are connected
 with relation in database.

Something like this:

```
----------
SECTION1--
ROW1
ROW2
----------
SECTION2--
ROW 3 
ROW 4
ROW 5
----------
SECTION3--
ROW 6
----------
SECTION 4--
ROW 7
ROW 8
```

and so on.

Any suggestion how to do it? I have no idea...

Comment: Use numberOfSectionsInTableView for sections, and numberOfRowsInSections for dynamic rows

Comment: I know how to make a simple tableview, I just dont know how to do it dinamically, like I asked.

Comment: I don't understand your meaning dynamically, it is meaning, you want to change the UITableView content according to database changes? or You want to edit UITableView rows?

Comment: You should use an `NSFetchedResultsController` (see the Apple Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)).  You would use `Task` as the entity for the underlying fetch, and specify `List` as the `sectionNameKeyPath`.

Comment: Your relationships are wrong. It should be one-to-many and many-to-one: `List <----->> Task`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment with the `NSFetchedResultsController` is the correct solution.

In the fetch request of your fetched results controller use entity `Task`. When creating the controller, set `sectionNameKeyPath` as `@"list"`, or whatever you called the to-one relationship in the task entity.